# Update to serilog.sinks.http to 8.0.0, and it stopped working

Tags: http, serilog

Recently updated the serilog.sinks.http to 8.0.0, and it failed to initialize httpsink from appsettings.json. If revert it to versions prior 8.0.0, everything works fine, the app is running under .net 6/7. I tried to add writeto Console, and that works, seems only for Http.
Any thought or suggestion would really appreciate.

Thanks

tried to add writeto:console, and that works, also tried to upgrade the serilog.aspnetcore to the latest version (7.0.0), but no luck.